# Extreme lag if I disable a monitor (laptop docking station setup)

Tags: 20.04, display, laptop, xrandr, docking

*Ubuntu 20 LTS, GNOME 3.36
Toshiba Satelittle L-50b, Acer monitors KG241Q, Targus 2k dock*

I have switched from a desktop PC to only using a laptop at my desk. I have a total of four screens which I use. But I have a different use case for each. The scenario in question, when at the desk, I want to disable the laptop screen and just use the two Acer monitors only. The laptop screen is not needed there. So to save energy and its life, I want it disabled.

I [wrote a simple Bash script](https://pastebin.com/9FF0zpsa) to manage all the monitors. Also, I have implemented [this solution](https://mensfeld.pl/2018/08/ubuntu-18-04-disable-screen-on-lid-close/) to disable or enable the laptop's screen on the lid switch. The laptop's screen does get disabled when I close the lid. But when I open the lid, the laptop screen doesn't turn on and I get extreme lag and programs take a few seconds to respond. The resource hog isn't CPU or memory according to *top*. It must be disk or graphics. If I run my xrandr script to enable the laptop screen, then the lag goes away. This happens even if I disable the screen using Ubuntu's native display program.

```
su -c  "xset -display :0 dpms force on &> /tmp/screen.lid" - $USER
```

from the lid method results in

```
No protocol specified
xset:  unable to open display ":0"
```

Same for :0.0. Though a -display argument of :1 doesn't produce an error. Yet, it doesn't turn on the laptop's screen or prevent the lag. Additionally, I could just run the script to correct the displays and remove the lag as temporary workaround. However, when my script is ran from the lid close or open script. xrandr says "Can't open display."

Any help would be appreciated!

```
dev@laptop:~$ xrandr -q
        
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5206 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
    eDP-1 connected 1366x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
       1366x768      60.00*+
       1360x768      59.80    59.96  
       1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
       1024x768      60.04    60.00  
       960x720       60.00  
       928x696       60.05  
       896x672       60.01  
       1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
       960x600       59.93    60.00  
       960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
       800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
       840x525       60.01    59.88  
       864x486       59.92    59.57  
       800x512       60.17  
       700x525       59.98  
       800x450       59.95    59.82  
       640x512       60.02  
       720x450       59.89  
       700x450       59.96    59.88  
       640x480       60.00    59.94  
       720x405       59.51    58.99  
       684x384       59.88    59.85  
       680x384       59.80    59.96  
       640x400       59.88    59.98  
       576x432       60.06  
       640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
       512x384       60.00  
       512x288       60.00    59.92  
       480x270       59.63    59.82  
       400x300       60.32    56.34  
       432x243       59.92    59.57  
       320x240       60.05  
       360x202       59.51    59.13  
       320x180       59.84    59.32  
    HDMI-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
       1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    30.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
       1920x1080i    60.00    59.94  
       1280x720      60.00    59.94  
       720x480       60.00    59.94  
       720x480i      60.00    59.94  
       640x480       60.00    59.94  
    DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DVI-I-4-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DVI-I-3-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    DVI-I-2-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
       1920x1080     60.00*+  74.99    50.00    59.94  
       1680x1050     59.88  
       1280x1024     60.02  
       1440x900      59.90  
       1280x800      59.91  
       1152x864      75.00  
       1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
       1024x768      70.07    60.00  
       800x600       60.32    56.25  
       720x576       50.00  
       720x480       60.00    59.94  
       640x480       66.67    60.00    59.94  
       720x400       70.08  
    DVI-I-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+3286+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
       1920x1080     60.00*+  74.99    50.00    59.94  
       1680x1050     59.88  
       1280x1024     60.02  
       1440x900      59.90  
       1280x800      59.91  
       1152x864      75.00  
       1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
       1024x768      70.07    60.00  
       800x600       60.32    56.25  
       720x576       50.00  
       720x480       60.00    59.94  
       640x480       66.67    60.00    59.94  
       720x400       70.08  
      1920x1080 (0x88) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
      1920x1080 (0x89) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
      1280x720 (0x90) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
            v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
      1280x720 (0x91) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
            v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
      1024x768 (0x4e) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
            v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
      800x600 (0x5d) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
            v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
      800x600 (0x5e) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
            v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
      720x480 (0x92) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
            v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
      720x480 (0x93) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
            v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
      640x480 (0x96) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
            v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
      640x480 (0x6c) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
            v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
      1920x1080 (0x88) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  60.00Hz
      1920x1080 (0xc9) 170.000MHz +HSync -VSync
            h: width  1920 start 1928 end 1960 total 2026 skew    0 clock  83.91KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1105 end 1113 total 1119           clock  74.99Hz
      1920x1080 (0xca) 148.500MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2448 end 2492 total 2640 skew    0 clock  56.25KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  50.00Hz
      1920x1080 (0x89) 148.352MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock  67.43KHz
            v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock  59.94Hz
      1680x1050 (0xcb) 119.000MHz +HSync -VSync
            h: width  1680 start 1728 end 1760 total 1840 skew    0 clock  64.67KHz
            v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1080           clock  59.88Hz
      1280x1024 (0xcc) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
            v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
      1440x900 (0xcd) 88.750MHz +HSync -VSync
            h: width  1440 start 1488 end 1520 total 1600 skew    0 clock  55.47KHz
            v: height  900 start  903 end  909 total  926           clock  59.90Hz
      1280x800 (0xce) 71.000MHz +HSync -VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1360 total 1440 skew    0 clock  49.31KHz
            v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  823           clock  59.91Hz
      1152x864 (0xcf) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1152 start 1216 end 1344 total 1600 skew    0 clock  67.50KHz
            v: height  864 start  865 end  868 total  900           clock  75.00Hz
      1280x720 (0x90) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
            v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  60.00Hz
      1280x720 (0xd0) 74.250MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1720 end 1760 total 1980 skew    0 clock  37.50KHz
            v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  50.00Hz
      1280x720 (0x91) 74.176MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock  44.96KHz
            v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock  59.94Hz
      1024x768 (0xd1) 75.000MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1328 skew    0 clock  56.48KHz
            v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  70.07Hz
      1024x768 (0x4e) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
            v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
      800x600 (0x5d) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
            v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
      800x600 (0x5e) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
            h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
            v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
      720x576 (0xd2) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   720 start  732 end  796 total  864 skew    0 clock  31.25KHz
            v: height  576 start  581 end  586 total  625           clock  50.00Hz
      720x480 (0x92) 27.027MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
            v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
      720x480 (0x93) 27.000MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   720 start  736 end  798 total  858 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
            v: height  480 start  489 end  495 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
      640x480 (0xd3) 30.240MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   640 start  704 end  768 total  864 skew    0 clock  35.00KHz
            v: height  480 start  483 end  486 total  525           clock  66.67Hz
      640x480 (0x96) 25.200MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.50KHz
            v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  60.00Hz
      640x480 (0x6c) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
            h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
            v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
      720x400 (0xd4) 28.320MHz -HSync +VSync
            h: width   720 start  738 end  846 total  900 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
            v: height  400 start  412 end  414 total  449           clock  70.08Hz
```

Comment: Please close this question. My install has gotten so unreliable I need to reinstall and will never inject the "solution" linked in the OP again.

Answer (score -2):

Solved-

sudo apt install evdi-dkms
Open menu -> Window Manager Tweaks -> Compositor and the disable -> Enable display compositing

This is in Linux Mint but the setting will also exist in other ubuntu distribution :-)

Comment: There is no "Window Manager Tweaks" in Ubuntu Mate 20.04. Here is a good example why LM related answers aren't suitable for Ubuntu.

Comment: I also made it work in Kubuntu in every distribution I made it work was a sitting with the option of compositing. F.eks. under window preference.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, perhaps some kind of similar setting is present in every distro you've used, however that's vague. If you knew how it is done in Kubuntu, perhaps you should have posted that, then the answer would have been on topic on AskUbuntu. As is, the answer is both off topic and vague.

Comment: Great answer or something. The solutions is in my answer